# C# converting int to Int64

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, ektron

we are in the process of upgrading our crappy cms system and the new assemblies have changed from int to int64.  I'm running into a problem when trying to build now.  I've tried casting but it doesnt seem to help.  here is one excerpt of code that is causing a problem.

```
IDictionary<int, string> aliases 
    = new UrlAliasApi().GetUrlAliasesByType(
        Company.DataLayer.Enumeration.UrlAliasType.Recipe);
foreach (ContentBase recipe in mergedResultset)
{
   // if alias exists, overwrite quicklink!
   string alias;
   if (aliases.TryGetValue(recipe.Id, out alias))
   {
      recipe.QuickLink = alias;
   }
}
```

The error is

> Error 323 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary.TryGetValue(int, out string)' has some invalid arguments

Its referring to `recipe.Id` which is an `Int64` value.

Any ideas of to deal with this?

Comment: You have a _namespace_ called `Enumeration`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C# is strongly typed, you can't convert like this. You need to cast the Int64 to an Int32 before you pass it in:

```
aliases.TryGetValue((int)recipe.Id, out alias)
```

Alternatively, you can change the definition of your dictionary:

```
IDictionary<Int64, string> aliases 
    = new UrlAliasApi().GetUrlAliasesByType(Company.DataLayer.Enumeration.UrlAliasType.Recipe)
                       .ToDictionary(kvp => (Int64)key.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: The first solution is incorrect.  It provides the potential for an overflow scenario to mathc an incorrect key.

Comment: I love this site and the great people on here. Great resource for a beginner .NET developer.  Thank You codekaizen.

Comment: @JaredPar - Agreed, the 2nd is safer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the `Int64` to an `int`, like this:

```
aliases.TryGetValue((int)recipe.Id, out alias)
```

Comment: In an overflow scenario the `Id` field could be rounded down to a different valid value and produce a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to use an `Int64` value in a place which takes an `int/Int32` type.  There is no implicit conversion here and hence the compiler errors.

The best way to fix this is to convert the `aliases` dictionary to use an `Int64` type as well.  It's always safe to convert an `int` to `Int64` so there is no information loss in this conversion.

Ideally you'd convert `GetUrlAliasesByType` to return an `IDictionary<Int64,string>`.  The rest of the system is now using `Int64` so this conversion makes sense.  Otherwise you can do the following

```
string alias; 
try { 
  if (aliases.TryGetValue(checked((int)recipe.Id), out alias)) 
  { 
    recipe.QuickLink = alias; 
  } 
} catch (OverflowException) { 
  // id not valid
}
```

The checked operation here is necessary because it prevents a silent overflow from producing a false match with `TryGetValue`

Answer (score 1):

Note that while you can cast Int64 to Int32 (or int), you could lose some data if the values that you are casting are larger than can be represented in an Int32.  In your case it might not matter, but I thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use `Dictionary<Int64, string>` instead of `Dictionary<int, string>`?